# Python: Pandas read csv: Downcasting while reading csv

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have the following problem. I want to read a large csv with million rows and hudnereds of columns. I want to downcast the dtypes for the columns. My approach is to read the csv and then downcasting it with `pd.to_numeric()`. I do not know the number of columns and their types. Is there any possibility to downcast while reading the csv so i do not have to touch the dataframe twice?

My current approch is:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(filePath, delimiter=delimiter, memory_map=True,engine='c', low_memory=True)
for column in df:
    if is_numeric_dtype(df[column]):
       df[column] = pd.to_numeric(df[column], downcast='signed')
       df[column] = pd.to_numeric(df[column], downcast='float')
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What about the `dtype` argument of `read_csv`: *dtype : Type name or dict of column -> type, optional

    Data type for data or columns. E.g. {‘a’: np.float64, ‘b’: np.int32, ‘c’: ‘Int64’}*

Comment: But in this case I would have to know which column should be converted to which dtype, isnt it? But i dont not know the order of my columns, the dtypes of my columns and so on

Comment: I would try to guess the types from the first rows. Depending on what your csv file contains, it could make sense. Or not, but only you can know  ;-)

Comment: your absolutley right, this is what i implement at the moment!! :)

Comment: works perfectly! Thanks for the idea!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If someone has the same problem, you can easily read the fist two lines, calulculate the dtypes and mapping your preferred dtypes over it and using it as dtype argument when reading the whole file:

**Example:**

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(filePath, delimiter=delimiter, nrows=2, low_memory=True, memory_map=True,engine='c')
mapdtypes = {'int64': 'int8', 'float64': 'float32'}
dtypes = list(df.dtypes.apply(str).replace(mapdtypes))
dtype = {key: value for (key, value) in enumerate(dtypes)}
df = pd.read_csv(filePath, delimiter=delimiter, memory_map=True,engine='c', low_memory=True, dtype=dtype)
```

Comment: I can't believe `pandas` doesn't have a more efficient way to do this. The `.read_csv()` method creates such a bloated dataframe by default and simple downcasting is a pain in the butt.